# Maximum number of strings in cbind?

Tags: r, string, syntax-error, cbind

I'm getting an error that looks like a syntax error, but it disappears when I break up my strings into smaller segments.

Essentially, I'm trying to use cbind on a long string of terms, coded as follows (I apologize for the horrible sidescrolling, I don't know how to wrap on here):

```
SpecificlistTrial <- c('london', 'birmingham', 'leeds', 'glasgow', 'sheffield', 'bradford', 'liverpool', 'edinburgh', 'mancehester', 'bristol', 'cardiff', 'leicester', 'dublin', 'newcastle', 'porto', 'oporto', 'lisbon', 'braga', 'sintra', 'guimaraes', 'guimarães', 'madrid', 'barcelona', 'valencia', 'seville', 'sevilla', 'bilbao', 'malaga', 'málaga', 'oviedo', 'gijón', 'gijon', 'alicante', 'zaragoza', 'las palmas', 'murcia', 'tenerife', 'ceuta', 'melilla', 'granada', 'vigo', 'cadiz', 'cádiz', 'san sebastian', 'san sebastián', 'donostia', 'valladolid', 'pamplona', 'cordoba', 'córdoba', 'paris', 'lyon', 'marseille', 'marseilles' 'aix-en-provence', 'toulouse', 'lille', 'bordeaux', 'nice', 'nantes', 'strasbourg', 'rennes', 'grenoble', 'la rochelle', 'rouen', 'toulon', 'montpellier', 'avignon', 'saint-etienne', 'saint-étienne', 'clermont-ferrand', 'brussels', 'antwerp', 'liege', 'liège', 'ghent', 'charleroi', 'bruges', 'anderlecht', 'leuven', 'molenbeek', 'amsterdam', 'eindhoven')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in "oza', 'las palmas', 'murcia', 'tenerife', 'ceuta', 'melilla', 'granada', 'vigo', 'cadiz', 'cádiz', 'san sebastian', 'san sebastián', 'donostia', 'valladolid', 'pamplona', 'cordoba', 'córdob"
```

This looks like a simple syntax error, but I haven't been able to figure out what is wrong with it, and when I try copying this segment into a separate list, there are no errors.  So I was wondering if there's a maximum number of terms/characters with cbind, or something else that might be causing the error besides syntax?

I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that

```
'marseilles' 'aix-en-provence'
```

didn't have a `,` separation.  Once we correct that it should work

```
SpecificlistTrial <- c('london', 'birmingham', 'leeds', 'glasgow', 'sheffield', 'bradford', 'liverpool', 'edinburgh', 'mancehester', 'bristol', 'cardiff', 'leicester', 'dublin', 'newcastle', 'porto', 'oporto', 'lisbon', 'braga', 'sintra', 'guimaraes', 'guimarães', 'madrid', 'barcelona', 'valencia', 'seville', 'sevilla', 'bilbao', 'malaga', 'málaga', 'oviedo', 'gijón', 'gijon', 'alicante', 'zaragoza', 'las palmas', 'murcia', 'tenerife', 'ceuta', 'melilla', 'granada', 'vigo', 'cadiz', 'cádiz', 'san sebastian', 'san sebastián', 'donostia', 'valladolid', 'pamplona', 'cordoba', 'córdoba', 'paris', 'lyon', 'marseille', 'marseilles' ,'aix-en-provence', 'toulouse', 'lille', 'bordeaux', 'nice', 'nantes', 'strasbourg', 'rennes', 'grenoble', 'la rochelle', 'rouen', 'toulon', 'montpellier', 'avignon', 'saint-etienne', 'saint-étienne', 'clermont-ferrand', 'brussels', 'antwerp', 'liege', 'liège', 'ghent', 'charleroi', 'bruges', 'anderlecht', 'leuven', 'molenbeek', 'amsterdam', 'eindhoven') 

length(SpecificlistTrial)
#[1] 83
```

Comment: Ah goodness, you're right.  I got caught up looking in the segment they gave me, and my eyes glossed over the others.  Thank you very much for it.

Comment: @Matthew While I don't agree with the 80 character width of code "standard", it is sometimes useful to catch gems like the one above.